# Unable to set default text in UITextView Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set default text for UITextView. Below is my code
I have used the text property to initialize but its not working. What am I missing here?

```
@implementation DetailViewController
{
    NSDictionary* inputFields;

}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    self.currentClaim = NULL;

    inputFields = @{
                    // These fields must match AppDelegate's newFormData method
                    // TODO: Refactor so we don't need this dependency.
                    @"actionPlan" : [self createTextAreaForActionPlan:@"Action Plan" at:CGPointMake(20.0f, 1200.0f)],
                   // createTextAreaForActionPlan
                    };

    return self;
}



- (UITextView*)createTextAreaForActionPlan:(NSString*)title at:(CGPoint)origin
{
    float height = [self createTextLabel:title at:origin];
    UITextView* textArea = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y + height, 660.0f, 100.0f)];
    [[textArea layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [[textArea layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    textArea.text =@"Default Text"; // this is the default text. how to show in UI TextView.
    [textArea setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
    [textArea setDelegate:self];
    [[self view] addSubview:textArea];

    return textArea;
}
```

Comment: this code worked for me with a hard-coded value of 100 for the `height` value. What's wrong?

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark without more details, but I would guess that the `init` method isn't being called. Add an `NSLog` statement in there to check. If e.g. your view controller is created from a storyboard, it'll use `initWithCoder:` instead. If that's the problem, then @rokjarc's advice to move the code to `viewDidLoad` will fix it, though it won't solve the underlying problem of your init code not being called.

Comment: MaxGabriel is correct: usually `initWithFrame:`, `initWithCoder:` or `initWithNibName:bundle:` are used with `UIVIewController`

Comment: init is called for sure.. when i add the line NSLog(@"Text: %@", textArea.text) .. shows the text in the console. when i try to set another property all works fine.. except Text property..

Answer (score 3):

You can only add views to `UIVIewController`'s view after it has been loaded.

So you should move your *initialization* code into

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

or into

```
- (void)loadView
```

if you are implementing it by yourself.

**EDIT:**

This code should work. I didn't test it though.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) 
    {
        self.currentClaim = NULL;    
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    inputFields = @{...};
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure whenever you access the `view` property of `UIViewController` for the first time `viewDidLoad` is called, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You have a valid point there. But as far as i know you shouldn't 'touch' the view property until after the initialization. On the other hand `[super init];` is called here. But: if `view` is not loaded then `[self loadView]` is called and only after it's execution `viewDidLoad` comes into play.

Answer (score -1):

**Working code**

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
- (UITextView*)createTextAreaForActionPlan:(NSString*)title at:(CGPoint)origin
{
    //float height = [self createTextLabel:title at:origin];
    UITextView* textArea = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y + 50, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    [[textArea layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [[textArea layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    textArea.text =@"Default Text"; // this is the default text. how to show in UI TextView.
    [textArea setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]];
    [textArea setDelegate:self];
    [[self view] addSubview:textArea];

    return textArea;
}
- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    //self.currentClaim = NULL;

    inputFields = @{
                    // These fields must match AppDelegate's newFormData method
                    // TODO: Refactor so we don't need this dependency.
                    @"actionPlan" : [self createTextAreaForActionPlan:@"Action Plan" at:CGPointMake(20.0f, 50.0f)],
                    // createTextAreaForActionPlan
                    };

    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self init];
}
```

**You Will got**

[image]

Comment: Seems a bit _strange_ to call `[self init]` from within `-(void) viewDidLoad` - don't do this: it calls the class constructor from allready constructed object.

Comment: More than a bit strange, I'd say. Find a better reason than this to call `init` outside of an object instantiation context.

Comment: @CarlVeazey; i was just being polite - of course this is not the correct way at all

Comment: Is this helpful to you??

Comment: this is fixed now... pain is my app is not structured in MVC and after setting the value it agains clears going forward in other section of the class :( ..